# react-native-splash-screen duplicated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I´m building an app with react native and expo in bare mode.
When i configure the icons in the res folder, the app is loading two splashes: one with a little icon and a blank rounded, and the correct splash that i could configure.

Can some one please help me? Im a beginner.

To make this job more easier, i´ll put here the github link.
https://github.com/zoesgod/bygrace

Please, im a beginner and i´d need some help.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't sticking with Managed Mode?  These days Bare Mode is really only useful if you are building your own custom module to be used in other (Managed Mode) apps.

Comment: Have you looked at Expo's [Splash Screen documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/) at all?  You should have `splash.image` set in your `app.json` (or `app.config.js`) file.

Comment: I´ll scale the app in future, It´s a bible app, so it´s recommended use managed?

Comment: I set the splash image, but he dont change anything.

Comment: I recommend Managed for 99.8% of use cases.  Check out [this article](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/what-react-native-what-expo).

Comment: When you modify an "native code" or the app.json/app.config.js file settings you need to recompile your "native app" and redeploy that to your testing environment (emulator/simulator or physical device).  Otherwise the "native app" will not reflect the changes (it has the old values compiled into it).  This is where using Managed Workflow and EAS Build make life a MILLION times easier than just a couple of years ago.

Comment: Could you take a look in to my app?

Comment: I did. That's where my comments come from. Your app.json has no splash settings in it.